# Creating a single process in C# to receive multiple Chrome Native Messages

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging, single-instance

Essentially what I want to do is have an application (a single process) that will stay open all the time and has a thread going listening to Chrome's Native Messaging.

My current understanding is that Chrome launches a separate process for each native message. If I were to use a Mutex to create a single process, I would then be unable to pass the standard input to the main process as I would have to launch the process again with the appropriate parameters first. Chrome probably does this similarly hence multiple processes.

It seems to me that there must be an intermediate process that communicates via sockets or something similar to notify the main process of Chrome's messages. Is this the case? Is there no way to implement this using a single process?

Input is much appreciated!

Also as a side note, Chrome seems to launch its native messaging app process silently (no display). Is this me doing something wrong or is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Using chrome.runtime.connectNative, you can create a long running native instance. Then you need to keep that javascript reference alive in a background script so you can reuse it.

manifest.json;

```
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
```

background.js;

```
var nativePort = null;
function getNativePort(){
  if (nativePort == null)
    nativePort = chrome.runtime.connectNative("...");
}
```

If you want to send messages from a content script, you'll have to forward it to your background script first.